# Location provider timestamp different between GPS provider and network provider?

Tags: android

I'm using the code from this article provided by google:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

to figure out a user's current location. I've been reading in other questions that the time provided by the GPS location provider is not comparable to the time provided by the network provider, or the system time:

[Android problem finding out how recent latest GPS fix is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418344/android-problem-finding-out-how-recent-latest-gps-fix-is/4481665#4481665)

Do we need to apply a fix to the google code sample in order for the time comparison to be done correctly? This is getting confusing especially with some other bugs in the location providers:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23937

Thanks

Comment: what kind of variance are you seeing between the timestamp on the readings and the current system time?

Comment: I haven't been noticing this on my test devices, but have received complaints from users that their location accuracy is sometimes off (different than what google maps is showing). I was wondering if this is what could be causing it. I'll try to get some more info on the locks I'm receiving. Was just wondering if maybe the users that are experiencing problems have their system time off etc.

Comment: To be honest, I just can't see where they'd be intentionally introducing a significant delay. I'd suggest logcat'ing a bunch of examples maybe ... sorry, not much help but I'm just afraid this might be the wrong tree.

Comment: Yeah I'll logcat a bunch and see, thanks for the info.

Comment: Did you find more info on this question? I have a user reporting a problem in its location trace and I suspect a different timestamp between the GPS and network location provider.