# Android Location -- Judging if last known location is too old

Tags: android, geolocation

I know that Location.getTime() returns something not compatible with system time. So how can I judge if the lastKnowLocation is too old so I won't use it before an update is made?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4418344/354247

Answer (score 1):

`Location.getTime()` returns time in milliseconds since epoch (January 1, 1970.). Convert it to Date and you will have the time the location was saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use  getElapsedRealtimeNanos () and minus the value away from elapsedRealtimeNanos () in System class to get age of location update

Answer (score 0):

Well how long before a location is stale is up to you.  The design pattern laid out [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) says use what ever location you have until you get a better one.  Think about my last known location.  I'm sitting at a laptop for the last six hours writing code and sharing on stackoverflow.

[image: location processing time flow]

1. Request a better location
2. Do whatever you want or need to do with the location you have.
3. When the better location comes in repeat step 2.