# How to know gps fix is available or not?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am working on app. When user click on button he will get current location using GPS. 
All is working fine but one problem.

**Problem**

There might be some location where gps will not work...like closed area...and gps can not find location...at that time it will return previously know location...Previously known location may be too older or wrong.
so at that time I want no location found instead of last location.

Is there any way to check if *fix* is available or not ?

Comment: What method are you using to start listening for location updates?

Comment: @3mpty I am using LocationManager with LocationListener.

Comment: Methods are gps / fused (Network)

Comment: I think that there is no option in location requestLocationUpdates to specify how long it will wait for fix before using last know location. You only can specify min time of searching.

Comment: @Shereef I am using gps

Comment: @PratikButani I know that..but just read question carefully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4481665/1318946

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android problem finding out how recent latest GPS fix is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418344/android-problem-finding-out-how-recent-latest-gps-fix-is)