# Fused Location Api Get time from GPS

Tags: android, time, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have an application that tracks users location.
My application uses `FusedLocationApi` , Google new way of getting device location using Google Play Services.

Provider of locations that i give from GPS is labeled as **fused**.

Because of application users may change device time, it is important to get real time from GPS.

Problem is that when i try to get time from `Location` object , it returns device time not GPS time.

Any solutions to get GPS time in this situation are appreciated.

```
private Location mLastLocation;    

public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {

        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        Date date = new Date(mLastLocation.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");            
        String time = dateFormat.format(date)
}
```

Comment: You must disable using Network as location provider.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418344/android-problem-finding-out-how-recent-latest-gps-fix-is

Comment: @skippy : Sorry for respond delay. You are right . This is possible with `LocationManager`, but how can i do this in `FusedLocationApi` ? Is this solution possible?

Comment: tell me, why you use FuseLocatinApi? What is special in this for you?

Comment: `FusedLocationApi` provides better accuracy with less battery drain.
It's a 'fused' location provider, so it uses a mixture of GPS and network provided location to give you a trade-off between accuracy and battery consumption. It can also be updated independently of the OS, so it has a shorter release cycle for updates.
see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc

Comment: I always get the local time, not the gps time. Did you get the right time from GPS?

Comment: @RafaelLeonhardt : With `LocationManager` it's possible to get right time from gps but i can't do it with `FusedLocationApi`. It's always returned device time instead of gps time.
Instead of this approach i force my application users to check automatic time and zone in setting.

Answer (score 1):

To get GPS UTC, do it in normal way:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
// not LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{   
    long utc = location.getTime();
    // ....
}
```

Comment: That's great, but as you mention this works in normal way ( `LocationManager` )

Comment: You can run this service occasionally, to count delta between GPS UTC and system time or time reported by FusedLocationApi